# Azure Synapse Billing Model for individuals?

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, subscription, azure-synapse

This is a question on the pricing model of the `azure synapse`, how it works, and understanding the cost accrued/accumulated for developers who are doing self-study and exploring/learning the services.

For the same purpose, I purchased a `pay-as-you-go` service. The first question is  -Is it the right scope/subscription for individuals who want to do practice or hands-on with `Azure services`?

Last Sunday i.e. 19 July 2020 (4 days ago) I provisioned 2 services (`SQL server` and `Synapse SQL pool (data warehouse)`).
`Synapse SQL pool` was set to 100 DWU and the service was immediately paused after creating it.
As per the billing I was expecting only to be charged 1.510 (since I had stopped the service and billing rate of 100 DWU is 1.510 per hour)

However on seeing today, i.e. 4 days since the services were provisioned I am seeing my accumulated charges to be 20.15 .
Does anyone know how this works out to be?

I have raised an SR for this and awaiting a response from Microsoft.

Appreciate it if anyone could give me some leads.

Regards
Lokesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did your bill include storage or was the $20 from compute alone? It would be reasonable for Synapse Data warehouse compute+storage: for 1 hour of DWU100 compute and 4 days of 1TB storage in central US region (1h * $1.51 + 4 * 24h * $0.19 = 1.51+18.24=$19.75).

The storage in ”old” Azure Data Warehouse comes with 1TB slots so you will be billed for 1TB even if you don’t use that all. With new Synapse on-demand you can use Azure Data Lake as your storage and it is billed by the actual usage.

Comment: Wow, Veikko that's spot on! I actually wrote to Microsoft and they said the charges are the combination of computing and storage. Where can I find the storage rates, please?
 
 Is this synapse on-demand a new service, can you please elaborate more on it. 
 
 Follow up question, I want to explore the following services
 1. adf
 2. azure synapse or dwh
 3. azure storage
 4. azure sql database
 
 Can you recommend the best subscription and best practises for it.

Comment: Good that this helped. The pricing is available at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/synapse-analytics/ section Azure Synapse SQL (Geneally available) / Data storage and snapshots. The fact that storage is billed by 1TB slots is hidden in the FAQ section. You can find pricing for the on-demand serverless version on the same page. The pricing structure is totally different for it.

Comment: Hi Veikko

So we have created a synapse workspace and a SQL pool. 

Do you know how it's billed? On the page, it says 5 $ per TB of data processed. Is it a one time cost? and how the data processed calculated? Is it the sum of data processed by various queries until now?

What about SQL pool, will we still be charged separately for the storage?

Would really appreciate if you could throw some light into it. 


Regards
Lokesh